# Generating even match-ups in Python

Tags: python

There are 8*K players where K is a positive integer. Each player has a certain skill level S.

I want to divide players into teams of four and then pair the teams so that each team plays against one other team. The goal is to have evenly matched pairs of teams (ideally, for any team pair, the Sum of S of all players in the team will be the same for both teams).

It only matters that any two teams that play against each other have the same (or as close as possible) Sum of S and not that all teams have the same Sum of S.

I'd like to do this in Python. What is a better way than just randomly generating and evaluating teams and pairs?

Example:

Let's say I have the following players:

- James, skill level (S) = 4
- Mike, S = 3
- Rosy, S = 4
- Edward, S = 1
- Nicholas, S = 4
- Ann, S = 4
- Rebecca, S = 3
- Lisa, S = 7

With 8 players, we only get two teams and one match-up. In this case, a possible output is:

Team 1 plays Team 2

Team 1: Lisa, James, Rebecca, Edward (Sum of S: 15)

Team 2: Nicholas, Rosy, Ann, Mike (Sum of S: 15)

Comment: can you give a concrete example of input and output? if I understand correctly, you can `sort` and `zip` the teams to match players ideally

Comment: I added an example to make it clear what I'm looking for. Input could be a dictionary with all the players, or a list etc. Output could be in any form, as long as it' clear which players form each team and what the team match-ups are.

Comment: Reformulate the problem as such: Partition the players into sets of 8 such that the sum of values in each set is even. Then, it becomes a multiple knapsack problem.